# Angular. Removing in a nested directive with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS and have problem with removing certain element in a nested custom directive with ng-repeat. [Here is my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wqp8Kr7H8G556JIEYcoP?p=preview)

I have such structure of nested directives:

```
<button ng-click="mc.addCat()">Add Category</button>

    <category ng-repeat="cat in mc.main.categories">
      <ul class="first-level">
          {{ $index +1 }}. Category
          <br>
          <input type="text" ng-model="mc.main.categories[$index].name">
          <button ng-click="cc.removeCat($index)">Del Category</button>
          <button ng-click="cc.addItem()">Add Item</button>

          <item ng-repeat="item in cc.cat.items track by item.id">
              <li class="second-level">
                {{ $parent.$index +1 }}.{{ $index +1 }}
                <input type="text" ng-model="mc.main.categories[$parent.$index].items[item.id].name">
                <button ng-click="ic.removeItem(item)">del</button>
              </li>
          </item>
      </ul>
    </category>
```

Adding and removing categories works as I need and the parent model updates.
But when I enter something in the item field, and then remove it, this item remains in the parent model.

I think my issue in nested scopes, could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the delete function in directive should call a method to update the main model....i have edited the plunker and forked the edit....

`

```
$scope.$on('updateItems',function(event,index,pindex){
      console.log(index);
      console.log(pindex);
      var sti = ""+index+"";
      delete vm.main.categories[pindex].items[sti];
});
```

`
here is the plunker link [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L36wfz6fzPMpeEXZEQwU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your concern! But if i add items, then delete any, then add new one or more, then try to delete, it removes not certain items from parent model. It is all in one first category, no more categories added.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your code is, your new `item` is being added and you are entering some `information` which is updating your parent model....

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mc.main.categories[$parent.$index].items[item.id].name">
```

While deleting the items, you are deleting the copy and the original object.

```
$scope.$on('delItem', function(event, data){
     var items = vm.cat.items;
     items.splice(items.indexOf(data), 1);
});
```

All the below function in category seems to be not working..

```
vm.cat = {
    items: [{
        id: 0,
        name: ''
    }]
};
vm.itemId = 0;
vm.addItem = function() {
    vm.itemId = vm.itemId + 1;
    var item = {
        id: vm.itemId,
        name: ''
    };
    vm.cat.items.push(item);
};
$scope.$on('delItem', function(event, data) {
    var items = vm.cat.items;
    items.splice(items.indexOf(data), 1);
});
```

Comment: Yes, i add items to categories and need parent model to be changed. It is updated if i type something to item input, But if i delete item with splice method the parent model has no changes